# Opening a pdf in Webiew

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I'm trying to load a pdf in a WebView with google docs, but the width of the psd is cut in half. I have tried different options but none of them looks great. 
This code show what i have already tried:

```
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.Settings.SetLayoutAlgorithm (WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.Normal);
        //webView.Settings.SetLayoutAlgorithm (WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SingleColumn);
        //webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
        //webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
        webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
        webView.LoadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Opening a new intent and downloading the pdf is not an option by the way. 
Also, i'm using the Xamarin framework.

I'm also seeing this alot in my application output:
[skia] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx clip not implemented

Comment: try changing `http` to `https`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String pdf = "http://ga.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/pdf-sample.pdf";
    String urlmain = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + pdf;
    wv.loadUrl(urlmain);
```

and make your webView height match_parent, it will surely work

Comment: Thanks, i will certainly give it a try